# Carrierwave persist uploads after redisplay

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cocoon-gem

I need to have rails remember the files a user has selected to upload after the form validation fails and redisplays the form. I think I have read every article on the web on this topic without any success.

The best and most complete solution I have found is:
http://www.liooo.engineer/blog/2014/11/22/building-multiple-file-upload-form-in-rails-way/

https://github.com/Liooo/carrierwave-cocoon-file-upload-app-demo

I have cloned the project from git, run it locally and yes it does work however when validation fails the attachments are remembered however the file upload box still displays "no file selected". This is confusing.

Has anyone managed to get rails + carrierwave to persist file uploads upon validation failure without having confusing messages displayed.

See post here with screenshots.
https://disqus.com/by/disqus_828B8YcIJd/

## Update

I have managed to partially resolve this somewhat and I hope someone can shed light on what is going on.

## form

```
<%= form_for(article, html: { id: "discussion-form" }, remote: true ) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 5, placeholder: "What do you want to discuss?", minlength: 10, maxlength: 1000 %>
  </div>
  <%= render partial: "attachments_form", locals: {f: f} %>
  <%= f.submit "Start discussion", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

## attachments_form

```
<%= f.fields_for :attachments do |builder| %>
  <% render 'attachment_fields', f: builder %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_association "Add an attachment", f, :attachments %>
```

## attachment_fields

```
<%= f.file_field :attachment, :multiple => false, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
<%= f.hidden_field :attachment_cache, :value => f.object.attachment_cache %>
<%= f.hidden_field :id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
<%= link_to_remove_association "remove", f %>
```

This does work and persists the selected file between form redisplays upon validation errors. If I change the "attachments_form" to wrap the form call in a div it stops working.

## attachments_form - stops working

```
<div id="tasks">
  <%= f.fields_for :attachments do |builder| %>
    <% render 'attachment_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association "Add an attachment", f, :attachments %>
</div>
```

Comment: having a similar issue, were you ever able to solve?

Comment: me too @danielpiestrak were either of you able to solve this?

Comment: Also having this same problem